# Converting Pine Script to V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am trying to convert an old script to V5 and get the error below.

```html
zigzag() =>
    _isUp = close >= open
    _isDown = close <= open
    _direction = _isUp[1] and _isDown ? -1 : _isDown[1] and _isUp ? 1 : nz (_direction[1]) 
    _zigzag = _isUp[1] and _isDown and _direction[1] != -1 ? ta.highest(2) : _isDown[1] and _isUp and _direction[1] != 1 ? ta.lowest(2) : na
```

> Undeclared identifier '_direction'

> Variable '_direction' is not found in scope 'zigzag', cannot register side effect

What is the problem here? Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

[Self referencing](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed) is not allowed from `v3` and above.

You should first define the variable and then use it.

```
zigzag() =>
    _isUp = close >= open
    _isDown = close <= open
    _direction = 0
    _direction := _isUp[1] and _isDown ? -1 : _isDown[1] and _isUp ? 1 : nz (_direction[1]) 
    _zigzag = _isUp[1] and _isDown and _direction[1] != -1 ? ta.highest(2) : _isDown[1] and _isUp and _direction[1] != 1 ? ta.lowest(2) : na
```

Comment: Thank you! it works now but it seems to compile upside down to the V1 version. Would you know why?